# CSS height in a table row

Tags: html, css

Trying hard to find why the first and the second rows have height higher (highlighted in yellow) than the other rows

[image]

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="min-width: 44px;"></th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="padding-top: 5px; width: 44px;"><span data-html="true" title="" data-placement="right" class="label label-success" style="margin-bottom: 3px; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 22px; padding-top: 2px;"></span><span style="position: relative; top: -15px; right: 0px; left: 16px;"><span style="font-family: RobotoCondensedRegular; font-size: 11px; color: #fff; text-align: center; display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 2px solid #5cb85c; border-radius: 100%; background-color: #f0ad4e;">0</span></span></td>
            <td>OOOOOOO</td>
            <td>RRRR</td>
            <td>DDDD</td>
            <td>XZZZZZ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="padding-top: 5px; width: 44px;"><span data-html="true" title="" data-placement="right" class="label label-success" style="margin-bottom: 3px; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 22px; padding-top: 2px;"></span><span style="position: relative; top: -15px; right: 0px; left: 16px;"><span style="font-family: RobotoCondensedRegular; font-size: 11px; color: #fff; text-align: center; display: inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; border: 2px solid #5cb85c; border-radius: 100%; background-color: #f0ad4e;">0</span></span></td>
            <td>OOOOOOO</td>
            <td>RRRR</td>
            <td>DDDD</td>
            <td>XZZZZZ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="padding-top: 5px; width: 44px;"><span data-html="true" title="" data-placement="right" class="label label-success" style="margin-bottom: 3px; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 22px; padding-top: 2px;"></span><span style="position: relative; top: -15px; right: 0px; left: 16px;"></span></td>
            <td>OOOOOOO</td>
            <td>RRRR</td>
            <td>DDDD</td>
            <td>XZZZZZ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="padding-top: 5px; width: 44px;"><span data-html="true" title="" data-placement="right" class="label label-success" style="margin-bottom: 3px; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 22px; padding-top: 2px;"></span><span style="position: relative; top: -15px; right: 0px; left: 16px;"></span></td>
            <td>OOOOOOO</td>
            <td>RRRR</td>
            <td>DDDD</td>
            <td>XZZZZZ</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center" style="padding-top: 5px; width: 44px;"><span data-html="true" title="" data-placement="right" class="label label-success" style="margin-bottom: 3px; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 22px; padding-top: 2px;"></span><span style="position: relative; top: -15px; right: 0px; left: 16px;"></span></td>
            <td>OOOOOOO</td>
            <td>RRRR</td>
            <td>DDDD</td>
            <td>XZZZZZ</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gx1j03xc/

Trying to keep the height as small as possible (in the same case as the other rows is ok). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extra space is to accommodate those circular spans you have that are relatively positioned. They still take up their original space even though to re-position them.

One solution is to give them absolute positioning instead like so:

```
td {
    position:relative;
}
td span:nth-child(2) {
    position:absolute !important;
    top: 17px !important;
    right:-16px !important;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gx1j03xc/1/)**

Note that the use of `!important` here is only to override your inline CSS which you should avoid at all costs.

Comment: Thanks. The inline CSS is here just because I am testing things. Thanks for the warning.